# Cannot use <algorithm> find on vector of struct

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, struct, iterator

so I'm having trouble using the  find func to  find a node in my vector of structs with the same 'char' value as specified. here is my code for my struct, I am overloading the comparison operator but still not having any luck

```
// STRUCT
struct alpha
{
   string morse;
   char letter;

   // overload the comparison operator
   bool operator==(const alpha& a) const
   {
      return letter == a.letter;
   }

};
```

and here is the code for my iterator

```
void testFunc(vector<alpha> &vect)
{
   std::vector<alpha>::iterator it;

   it = find(vect.begin(), vect.end(),'e');
   if(it != vect.end())
   {
   // do anything if we ever get here
   }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, my code will not even compile i get the error

```
Invalid operands to binary expression ('alpha' and 'int')
```

Comment: `bool operator==(const code& a) const` what is a `code`?

Comment: Where do you define the type `code`?

Comment: Better data structure could be `std::map<char,std::string>` or hash map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to define an equality operator between your struct and a char

```
bool operator==(const char c) const
   {
      return letter == c;
   }
```

Comment: Does `std::find()` guarantee that `value` will be on the right side of expression?

Comment: yes the function uses operator== to compare the individual elements to val

Comment: @Slava: Yes. from 25.3.5/1: *"Returns: The first iterator i in the range [first, last) for which the following corresponding conditions hold: *i == value..."*

Answer (score 0):

`std::find` cannot implicitly convert a `char` to a `alpha`. You need to provide a constructor which will perform that conversion, or supply an `alpha` object that you create to the `find` function, or add another `operator==` function that compares against a `char`.

<strike>Also, the `operator==` function you defined is comparing to a `code` object? Is that supposed to be correct?</strike>

Comment: thanks mate, fixed that "bool operator==(const alpha& a) const" still have the same error though :(

Comment: He said you need to provide ctor with single argument of type `char` that can be used for type conversion.

Comment: If you have information in your answer which is wrong or irrelevant, just delete it. I don't see the point of leaving it in but striking a line through it.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley The OP posted a comment on this answer referring to the deleted section. If I remove it entirely, it would create confusion as to what they were talking about. I'll remove it if the OP decides to delete their comment.

Answer (score 0):

In `find(vect.begin(), vect.end(),'e');`, the third argument of `find` is not an `alpha` object. You should constuct such an object beforehand :

```
alpha eKey;
eKey.letter='e';
vector<alpha>::iterator it = find(vect.begin(), vect.end(), eKey);
```

This will make a propper use of the `find` function.